# cordova open native activity with custom view

Tags: android, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

How I can open a native Android UI (xml) using a cordova plugin?
I know how to call the Intent, but I don't know how to put and reference the xml file to load.

I searched in SO, but I don't find anything that could help with the problem.

here a piece of my code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Teste.class);
 this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, (CAMERA + 1) * 16 + returnType + 1);
```

And:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

   //HERE IS THE PROBLEM, HOW TO REFER activity_main.xml, because i'dont have the R.class
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

};
```